# Smallest string which contains all $27$ combinations of $1$, $2$, and $3$ as substrings

Tags: combinatorics

What is the smallest string of $1$s, $2$s and $3$s such that it contains each of $27$ substrings of $1$s $2$s and $3$s (repetitions included)?

Comment: What is ${\large s}$ ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin what do you mean?  Here s is just denoting a plural.

Comment: I think it would be much clearer to everybody if you give an example. For example with 1s and 2s.

Comment: For $1$s and $2$s it is known that the minimum length, here $10$, can be achieved.  $2111212221$ does the trick.  It is also cyclic, so you can make a ring of 8 that works.  I suspect the minimum of $29$ can be achieved for $123$ as well.

Comment: Example for 1s and 2s. Construction is 22112, since it contains substrings 22, 21, 11, 12, which are all the possible substrings formed with 1 and 2.

Comment: I disagree with Mr. Ross Millikan's, since the above shows a construction that gives answer of 5.

Comment: Ross Millikan is talking about substrings of length 3, not of length 2.

Answer (score 8):

Certainly you need length at least $29$, since there need to be at least $27$ substrings.

It turns out we can do exactly $29$; this is the $3$-ary [De Bruijn Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence)  of order $3$ ($3$-ary since there are $3$ different symbols, 1,2, and 3, and of order $3$ since we want all substrings of length $3$ to appear).  Here's one way of doing it:

> 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 0 0

Note that if we allowed substrings to wrap around the end of the sequence, we wouldn't need the two 0s on the end.